# Grails groovy - render pure js code

Tags: javascript, grails

this is a duplicate of [Executing groovy statements in JavaScript sources in Grails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/425618/executing-groovy-statements-in-javascript-sources-in-grails)

with one difference, i just want to render the js-code, no script tags around it

imagine someone loads a script from my server inside his html like

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="mywebsite.com/xyJs/xyz"></script>
```

and i want to render the "content" of the request

inside the controller i parse the `/xyz` and find out what must be inside the script and an absolute link for the src of iframe
i need to run this groovy script too 
i´m trying to do this like

```
    render "document.writeln('<iframe src=\"${grailsApplication.config.grails.serverURL}/superStuff/stuff23/${profil.slugs}\" name=\"SuperStuff\" width=\"300\" height=\"600\" align=\"left\" scrolling=\"no\" marginheight=\"0\" marginwidth=\"0\" frameborder=\"0\" ></iframe>');"
```

but the browser just ignores the `document.writeln('`
and treat the iframe like an html element and renders its content

how can i deklare that its just a tiny bit of js-code without setting script tags?

i also tried to render a view like

```
render(view:'SuperStuff',model:[profil:profil])
```

and inside the view SuperStuff is

```
<%@ page contentType="text/javascript; UTF-8" %>
document.writeln("<iframe src='${grailsApplication.config.grails.serverURL}/superStuff/stuff23/${profil.slugs}' name='SuperStuff' width='300' height='600' align='left' scrolling='no' marginheight='0' marginwidth='0' frameborder='0' ></iframe>");
```

but this also doesnt work and renders the content of the iframes´s src
what i doing wrong ?

for any hint, this makes me fuzzy, thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

yeaaaah got that one fixed

```
render contentType: 'text/javascript', text: "document.writeln('<iframe src=\"${grailsApp......."
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe, your controller works just as expected: it returns the javascript-code exactly as you want: your call to document.writeln(). Please use the Network-Panel of [Firebug](https://getfirebug.com/network), [Chrome DevTools](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/network) or similar to verify this.

However, the js-code will immediately be executed which results in the inclusion of the specified iframe-element on the current position, as explained for example [here](http://javascript.info/tutorial/document-write).